# PHP Raspberry Pi system() echo prints

Tags: php, stdout

I have little problem. When I type in PHP on my Raspberry Pi machine this:

```
system("echo hello");
```

It prints to the web page. Why? Why it doesn't print into terminal?

I didn't see it on my PuTTY.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "`system` — Execute an external program and display the output". Output of `echo hello` is `hello`, and you are surprised to see this displayed?

Comment: Yes. I though it is like typing it to terminal.
So GPIO commands doesn't return anything, so they just execute?
edit: or PHP can't display their output ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with `system`. This function returns whatever the executed program printed to `stdout`. In this case it is "hello".

### Using `wall` to print to everyone

As Jasen suggested, you could use `wall` to print it to everyone using the system. This is useful if you don't know the number of the tty, but it displays a banner to the terminal if you don't run it as root.

```php
system("echo test | wall");
```

### Manually printing to the terminal

To print manually, without the banner and root, you can add your apache server user to `tty` group, like so: (replace the user)

```php
sudo usermod -a -G tty WEB_SERVER_USER
```

Then you could do something along those lines:

```php
system("your command > /dev/pts/0");
```

or

```php
$output = system("your command");
file_put_contents('/dev/pts/0', $output);
```

That of course assumes that your terminal is mapped to `/dev/pts/0`. `ls /dev/pts/` to see the list.

### Redirecting `stderr`

In addition to the above, if your program outputs to `stderr`, you need to attach `2>&1` at the end of your command, for example:

```php
system("your_command 2>&1 | wall");
```

This will redirect both streams.

### Running your script in the terminal

You can also run your script in terminal, using php-cli. To install cli, use:

```php
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Then, in your script, you can use `echo system("your_command 2>&1");` and run it in the terminal:

```php
php script.php
```

Comment: Well, it didn't print anything, is that caused by using a PuTTY? Shoud I connect a HDMI cable?

Comment: What does `ls /dev/pts/` show? Using putty should work.

Comment: 0 ptmx
Note: I have set my pi accout's default folder as apache folder.

Comment: See my updated answer, try using `wall` and see if it works. Try it with `echo` to be sure that the command actually outputs something to `stdout` (your might be outputting to `stderr`, it's a possibility).

Comment: when you type `mesg` does it say `is y` ?

Comment: @Jasen It does by default on raspian, for the record.

Comment: is y
And can you explain, what is 2>&1 ?

Comment: |wall worked eh.. good


Broadcast Message from www-data@rasp
        (somewhere) at 21:06 ...

hello

Comment: Every program, normally (in terminal) has 3 standard IO streams attached: standard input, standard output and standard error output. `system()` only captures standard output and `2>&1` redirects errors to standard output so that it is also captured.

Comment: @sebi  echo definately outputs to stdout

Comment: @Jasen Ah right, I missed the permission part. (It should be fine to add apache to tty group on rpi, but you're right). Ad echo output, OP mentioned using other commands, which may not, so I added the redirect to the example.

Answer (score 0):

this is beacuse in a web context stdout is the result returned to the browser

if you want to write to terminals of logged in users

```
$wall=popen("wall","w");
fwrite($wall,"Hello!\n");
pclose($wall);
```

they must have "mesg" turned on. (I think on is the default)

the command `mesg y` will turn it on, `man mesg` for more info.

Comment: Well, If I would use GPIO commands, PHP can't display their output, so they just execute?
And how can I "echo" something to terminal thru PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The system function does not executes the command in any attached tty, that is why don't see any output on the tty attached to your Putty session.

If you want to send commands to your GPIO pins in the Pi through PHP you can use the system function to do things like `system("echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/xyz)` but be aware that php must be run with root privileges which isn't not by default in the Apache websever.